# Which of the following two sentences is grammatically correct, and why?

Tags: grammaticality

Sentence one:

> Has any of your employees been sick this week?

Sentence two:

> Have any of your employees been sick this week?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "any of them" used with a singular or plural verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/475028/is-any-of-them-used-with-a-singular-or-plural-verb)

Answer (score 0):

Neither.  The two possible correct sentences are:

- Have any of your employees been sick this week?

("Employees" plural, "have" plural)

- Has any employee of yours been sick this week?

("Employee" singular, "has" singular)

Comment: Thanks... The speaker incorrectly but quite confidently, so that threw me off